# Create 8.3 name for an existing directory

Tags: ntfs, filenames

I have a machine that initially had [8.3 filename creation disabled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007/).  However, this was causing issues with some legacy software, so it was re-enabled.  I'm wondering if it's possible to go back and "add" 8.3 filenames to certain existing directories.

For example, say I have a directory named "C:\name with spaces" and I get the following output when I run "dir /x":

```
C:\>dir /x
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 6873-65B8

 Directory of C:\

04/09/2010  01:57 PM    <DIR>                       name with spaces
...
```

I'd like to somehow add an 8.3 name for the directory without recreating it, and then get the following:

```
C:\>dir /x
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 6873-65B8

 Directory of C:\

04/09/2010  01:57 PM    <DIR>          NAMEWI~1     name with spaces
...
```

I tried the 'rename' command but it didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490642.aspx:

```
 fsutil file setshortname <PathName> <shortname>
```

This worked, but required me to boot into recovery console (on win 7 this is via tapping <kbd>F8</kbd> before you boot.)
Also required me to navigate to the disk in question, and run this first:

```
fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 0
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 0` is the command that requires a reboot to take effect. `fsutil file setshortname <PathName> <shortname>` does not.

Comment: I don't know about setting the behavior with fsutil requires a reboot, but directly setting the registry variable NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation to 0 did not require a reboot for me on Win 7. Immediately, short file names began to be created from new files with long names.

(In my case, some poorly written Intel or Microsoft system update had set it to 1 a week ago. Silently even. $#@%&# !!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Robocopy** source destination /e /FAT. Go to cmd-mode, type **Robocopy /?** for full instruction set

Answer (score 0):

Nice utility for 8.3 names fix
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEsQH.png
[manual](https://support.trumpetinc.com/index.php?pg=kb.printer.friendly&id=42)
[link](http://resources.trumpetinc.com/getresource/Trumpet-WDForce8dot3Names.exe)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.