# How to force short name (8dot3) generation?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

I have a problem with windows windows shortnames. Sometimes the short names do not seem to be generated for "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)".

I verified that short name generation is enabled with `fsutil behavior query disable8dot3 C:` which tells me that the system wide setting is `2` (per volume) and the local value is `0` (create 8dot3 names).

It should look roughly like this (note that is is a german 32bit copy):

```
C:\>dir /a /x

 Verzeichnis von C:\

21.12.2011  00:17    <DIR>                       $Recycle.Bin
14.07.2009  05:53    <VERBINDUNG>   DOCUME~1     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
09.01.2011  15:35    <VERBINDUNG>   DOKUME~1     Dokumente und Einstellungen [C:Users]
27.11.2013  15:11     2.147.016.704              pagefile.sys
14.07.2009  03:37    <DIR>                       PerfLogs
26.11.2013  17:31    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
08.11.2013  21:58    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     ProgramData
09.01.2011  15:35    <VERBINDUNG>   PROGRA~3     Programme [C:\Program Files]
09.01.2011  15:35    <DIR>                       Recovery
26.11.2013  17:40    <DIR>          SYSTEM~1     System Volume Information
23.01.2011  15:00    <DIR>                       Temp
11.01.2011  20:56    <DIR>                       Users
08.11.2013  14:53    <DIR>                       Windows
```

However on another machine (64bit copy), this looks like
    C:>dir /a /x

```
 Verzeichnis von C:\

21.12.2011  00:17    <DIR>                       $Recycle.Bin
14.07.2009  05:53    <VERBINDUNG>   DOCUME~1     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
09.01.2011  15:35    <VERBINDUNG>   DOKUME~1     Dokumente und Einstellungen [C:Users]
27.11.2013  15:11     2.147.016.704              pagefile.sys
14.07.2009  03:37    <DIR>                       PerfLogs
26.11.2013  17:31    <DIR>                       Program Files
26.11.2013  17:31    <DIR>                       Program Files (x86)
08.11.2013  21:58    <DIR>                       ProgramData
09.01.2011  15:35    <DIR>                       Recovery
26.11.2013  17:40    <DIR>          SYSTEM~1     System Volume Information
23.01.2011  15:00    <DIR>                       Temp
11.01.2011  20:56    <DIR>                       Users
08.11.2013  14:53    <DIR>                       Windows
```

As you might have noticed, the short names are missing for the program folders.

The question is now how to generate them, because I need those short names for a few older scripts.
I tried with `fsutil file setshortname "Program Files" "PROGRA~1"`, but this just gives me `Access denied.`.

Comment: The only way i know how Windows is going to re-generate the short-name is to copy the directory and delete the original. Of course that is not going to work for the `Program Files`. It's not possible to adjust the scripts? Also, i hope the script is not thinking the `Program Files`-directory is always `PROGRA~1` because if that's the case your script will run in some serious trouble eventually because the short-names are not always the same. You could also ask for help upgrading the scripts to the long-name (instead of the short-name) findfirst etc. (if at all possible).

Comment: I am aware of the issues with short names and I would never write those scripts myself. I would always use the env vars for this (``%programfiles%``). Renaming does indeed not work. Maybe I can do this from offline? Could be a work-around.

Comment: did you try running the command as admin? [Create 8.3 name for an existing directory](https://superuser.com/q/129295/241386)

Comment: Sure. It did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like i said in my comment...  The only way i know how Windows is going to re-generate the short-name is to copy the directory and delete the original. (not doable for the "Program Files" directory.)

It would be best to change the script to use long file- and folder-names. If the script uses `PROGRA~1` it will get in trouble with installations where the drive was cloned in a way the directories where copied back. For example if `ProgramData` is copied first onto the disk it will be named `PROGRA~1` and `Program Files` will be named `PROGRA~2`.

**There is an option to keep the scripts working for now**:

You could create a **directory-junction** from `PROGRA~1` to `C:\Program Files`. That way the scripts keep working and you have time to change them.

```
mklink /J "C:\PROGRA~1" "C:\Program Files"
```

Output of `mklink /?`:

```
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

Comment: Good idea to use a directory jump :)

Comment: Are changes made by `mklink` permanent or they just work in batch script which is being run? Sorry I don't have enough info about symlinks and junctions.

Comment: @AlirezaMohamadi Changes made with `mklink` are permanent. Just like `mkdir`.

Answer (score 10):

To define shortnames (8dot3) for Program files do the following:

1. Restart computer
2. upon boot start in safemode with cmd prompt (F8 on my computer)
3. Log in
4. from cmd prompt enter the following cmds

   ```
   fsutil 8dot3name query
   fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 0
   fsutil file setshortname "Program Files" PROGRA~1
   dir /X
   ```

You should now see the shortname defined for program files.  If you'd like, set the 8dot3name behavior back to the original setting which was returned by the query cmd.

Comment: FWIW- I didn't need to reboot my computer for any of this. Also, you can selectively enable/disable 8.3 on different drives. The registry location for all these settings is HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\Ntfs*. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121007

Comment: Yes, I just stayed where I was and did :