# How comes that short filenames (8.3) are created in one partition and not in another of the same disk?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, ntfs, filenames

I run a 64-bit Windows 10 PC with a single hard disk with two NTFS partitions, C: and D:. Short filenames (8.3) are created in C: but not in D:

1. How is this possible, and
2. Can I enable short filenames in D: too?

Comment: Do you mean when you type `dir /x` on D:, there are no 8.3 names?

Comment: Yes, something like that. But this is quite an old question. I have solved it (fortunately!) since then. There's a flag in the registry for a drive to accept short names. For drive C: it was set  by default, but not  for drive D:, not.  (Same disk, different partition! Weird, eh?)  Anyway, after I turned it ON I can see and use short names in D: too. It is very essential for me, because --as an old timer-- I work a lot in MSDOS! :)

Comment: I use old compilers etc too.  They only accept 8.3 file and directory names.  I normally have to do a dir/x to find out what the actual names is.

Answer (score 10):

The global setting for *8.3 name creation* is controlled by the key `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation`. The default value is 2 which means **allowing each volume to have *its own local 8.3 name creation setting***. The available settings for that key are:

- 0: Enables 8dot3 name creation for all volumes on the system.
- 1: Disables 8dot3 name creation for all volumes on the system.
- 2: Sets 8dot3 name creation on a per volume basis.
- 3: Disables 8dot3 name creation for all volumes except the system volume.

When the value is 2, the setting for each volume can be get/set by the [`fsutil 8dot3name`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name) command

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil 8dot3name query
The registry state is: 2 (Per volume setting - the default).

C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil 8dot3name query c:
The volume state is: 0 (8dot3 name creation is enabled).
The registry state is: 2 (Per volume setting - the default).

Based on the above settings, 8dot3 name creation is enabled on c:
```

> How is this possible

The setting **doesn't apply to all partitions** in the whole system as said above. That means ***someone disabled 8.3 name creation in D:***. With `fsutil` you can even add/remove 8.3 names for a specific file with [`fsutil file setshortname`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-file)/[`fsutil 8dot3name strip`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name) regardless of the system/volume setting so another possible but less likely solution is that all the 8.3 names have been deleted and new files haven't been added to the volume

Since Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 **newly formatted volumes will have [8.3 name generation disabled by default](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html)**. This is probably the situation in your PC

> In fact, recent versions of Windows Server don’t even enable 8.3 naming when you format new data volumes.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/josebda/windows-server-2012-file-server-tip-disable-8-3-naming-and-strip-those-short-names-too

---

> Can I enable short filenames in D: too?

Yes, of course. To enable the setting on D: run

```
fsutil 8dot3name set D: 0
```

and to disable it

```
fsutil 8dot3name set D: 1
```

---

Related:

- [How to force short name (8dot3) generation?](https://superuser.com/q/681330/241386)
- [Create 8.3 name for an existing directory](https://superuser.com/q/129295/241386)

Comment: 'phuclv',  thank you for your answer, but maybe you missed the answer I have already given, in which I found the solution and you have just repeated it  here. Then you wonder why I don't accept answers …

Comment: @Apostolos no, you found the key but you didn't really answer any of your questions and still wondered *"How one partition has short names and the other not? The registry key applies to all NTFS file systems!", "How is this possible, and Can I enable short filenames in D: too?"*. Because the real answer is to use `fsutil` and not the global registry key

Comment: please read through my answer instead of just looking at the first sentence and thought that it's what you answered

Comment: Well, I have provided the solution and that's a closed case as far as the **specific question** is concerned, for me and others with the same problem. Whatever else is proposed is **outside the question**, except of course if it's **an additional solution**, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Apostolos which specific question have you answered? "How comes that short filenames (8.3) are created in one partition and not in another of the same disk?" or "Can I enable short filenames in D: too?"

Answer (score -1):

Meanwhile, I found the right question to ask in Bing, which led me to the solution from http://omtool.com/documentation/HPCR/v1.2.0/ServerHelp/Enabling_8.3_name_creation.htm:

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` in the registry and set `NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation` to 0. (Default is 2). I tried it and it works.

But the first question still holds: How one partition has short names and the other not? The registry key applies to all NTFS file systems!

So, I don't delete my question for another also reason: other people might have the same question and cannot find the solution in the Web, as I couldn't myself.

Comment: `The registry key applies to all NTFS file systems!` it doesn't when the setting value is 2 or 3

Comment: Right. And the question is about NTFS file systems!

Comment: I don't get that. You didn't answer your own questions above: *How is this possible, and Can I enable short filenames in D: too?* How does this show that separate settings for C: and D: are possible and how to enable that on D:?