# How to get %~dp0 in long name format

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

On Windows 10, I have created the following folder:

```
C:\BigLongFolderName
```

If I run the following test.bat from Windows Explorer with "Run as Administrator" on the right-click context menu from within the above folder, I get a shortened 8.3 folder name.

**test.bat**

```
echo "%~dp0"
echo %~dp0
```

**Output:**

```
C:\windows\system32>echo "C:\BIGLON~1\"
"C:\BIGLON~1\"

C:\windows\system32>echo C:\BIGLON~1\
C:\BIGLON~1\
```

How do I get the long folder name in Windows 10 when using "Run as Administrator"?

The output I want to see is `C:\BigLongFolderName\`

I do literally have a folder called C:\BigLongFolderName on my machine.

If I run the same **test.bat** by double-clicking on it (instead of "Run as Administrator") then I am echoed the full `C:\BigLongFolderName` path as I would expect. Why does "Run as Administrator" not give me the long path?

I moved this question from Stackoverflow as "its not a programming question".

The following post suggests that I should be getting long name format by default and indeed my 2 of my collegues do:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567809/batch-extract-path-and-filename-from-a-variable

Please note that I not want to convert 8.3 names into long names. I want the long names to be returned sames as other people are getting.

Comment: You do understand, don't you?, that you have a folder named C:\BIGLON~1\.  The folder has two names: a SFN (short filename) and an LFN (long filename).  Those are both valid names for the same folder.

Comment: That's strange. For me it's working correctly. Some few notes... You say you run this from the Windows Explorer. If you do, and you don't have `pause` in the `test.bat`, you'll see a black screen disappear very quickly. Not quickly enough for you to copy and paste your result. I used `pause` and got `C:\BigLongFolderName` twice. I also ran this in `cmd.exe` and got the same result. HOWEVER, if you run this from `command.com` you will get the short names (`command.com` is the old 16-bit command line for DOS programs). (note the difference in `cmd.exe` and `command.com`)

Comment: Also... if you run it directly from `C:\BIGLON~1` you'll always get the short 8.3 folder name.

Comment: @TOOGAM Yes, I understand that short and long names are the same folder. Imagine if you subst' a logical drive (such as J:) many times a day to different folders all endng in version numbers blahblahblah1.0, blahblahblah1.1 etc and you want to double-check which folder you are currently subst' to. I usually type in 'subst' and it tells me. You can't tell with 8.3 format.

Comment: @Rik, its definitely running cmd.exe. Its in the Task Manager and yes, I have confirmed this by echo'ing our followed by 'pause'. There is something odd with this machine's configuration. The reason I'm trying to do all of this is because 'subst' works fine in normal user context. I subst a drive and I see the LFN association. I try to get %~dpo so that I can then call subst again in the Administrator context but calling some batch code. But.. since %~dp0 is in SFN, I cannot get the Administrator context to behave the same as user context. BTW "net use" is not an option in my case.

Comment: @SparkyNZ Wait... you were talking about a folder on the C-drive in your question. Now you are saying subst and other driver. I was also confused by the `C:\windows\system32>` in your output. When you run a batch from the Windows Explorer (by double clicking it) the current directory is the directory that file is in. Your `C:\windows\system32>` suggests that that is not on the C: drive but on some network drive. Could you explain if you are just talking about `C:\BigLongFolderName` or something else ??

Comment: @SparkyNZ Look at the following screenschot. https://i.imgur.com/KlAAr3n.png What you said in your question should work just fine. So please edit your question with your exact example. Also note that if you run a 16bit command in your script, after that all your directories will be short-named (assuming you have a 32bit Windows-version).

Comment: @Rik, the missing piece of information is that I should have stated run test.bat as an Administrator - then you will see the C:\Windows\system32 that I mentioned above. The example takes place on the C: drive entirely - no network drives are involved. If you run the test.bat just by double-clicking on it, C:\BigLongFolderName is printed. Run as Administrator, C:\BIGLON~1 is printed.

Comment: @SparkyNZ username should not matter; and neither should permissions. What happens when you run it (in the same way) as a non-Administrator?

Comment: You may be able to fix this (or get a helpful error message) by [disabling 8.3 filenames](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/121007/how-to-disable-8-3-file-name-creation-on-ntfs-partitions), and then renaming the folder to ensure it gets a new directory entry (without the 8.3 duplicate pointer). You probably should backup your registry before trying this.

Comment: @jpaugh That worked! I had to rename the folder as you suggested but after running "fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 1" I got the full path name. Unfortunately I'll have to rename all of my folders and subfolders though. Thank you for your constructive answer.

Comment: @SparkyNZ I'm glad it worked. I suppose you could rename the folders back to their original names; and if so, you could automate it with a batch or PowerShell script. BTW, the switch to PowerShell is difficult, but worth it.

Comment: @SparkyNZ I posted my comment as an answer for posterity's sake!

Comment: @jpaugh I reckon you should change your comment into an answer which I will accept. This will solve my overall problem moving forward.

Comment: @SparkyNZ Even when right-clicking test.bat and running it as administrator, I still get the long name here (but indeed with the `c:\windows\system32`-prompt). So I can't reproduce your problem. But I'm glad you've got it working now.

Comment: @Rik Your machine must be set up to 'not create 8.3' filenames are jpaugh suggested - so you are one of the lucky ones.

Comment: @SparkyNZ No, my machine does creates 8.3 names (it's default). I checked with `dir /x` to make sure `C:\BigLongFolderName` had `C:\BIGLON~1` as 8.3 name. You could try this batch file on another machine or in a Virtual machine to test if it's something with your installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Disable 8.3 file names](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/121007/how-to-disable-8-3-file-name-creation-on-ntfs-partitions). You'll need to rename existing folders to clean up the existing 8.3 filename entries. There may be a tool to clean these up automatically, but I'm not sure. ([`fsutil file setshortname C:\BigFolderName ""`](https://superuser.com/a/129306/86708) may work.)